# Microphone Issue

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, microphone, audio-jack

I recently dual-booted my Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I am using HP br106tx, since this laptop contains only one 3.5mm jack for both mic and speaker whenever I plug my headphones my headphones work however mic of my headphones are damaged hence I would like to use my internal laptop mic.

My internal mic works fine without headphones but when I connect the headphones it switches to headphone mic. This image below is from Pulse Audio control.

[image]

In the image you can see "Microphone (plugged in)" and the status of my internal mic changes to "Internal Microphone (unplugged)". Even if I select my internal mic with Pulse Audio control it does not work.

I have no issue using my laptop mic in Windows along with my headphones. If anyone got any leads kindly help.